# Discriminant of minimal polynomial of an elementary symmetric function of roots

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, discriminant

Through various examples I have noticed the following result which seems to be true. I do not see how to prove it, nor how to find counterexamples.

Let $P(X)$ be a monic irreducible polynomial with integer coefficients. Let $S$ be any nonempty, proper subset of the set roots of $P$ in a splitting field. Let $\theta$ be an elementary symmetric function in the elements of $S$. Then the discriminant of the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ divides some power of the discriminant of $P$.

Comment: Can you give an example where it's true?

Comment: The simplest example is when $P$ is quadratic. In that case the set $S$ can only consist of one root of $P$, so $\theta$ must be a root of $P$. Hence, the discriminant of the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ is equal to the discriminant of $P$. It's also not hard to work through the case where $P$ is cubic.